# Design Question: Reject Requests at Scale

Tags: design, api-design, large-scale-project

Usecase:

- TeamA: Adds 5000 IDs to a blacklist per day and notifies other teams by publishing an SNS message per ID added that all other Teams listen to.
- TeamB: Gets 4K TPS to its API, and if a given ID is within that blacklist, it must reject it that request.

Notes:

- When TeamA updates their blacklist, TeamB and all other Teams, have 30days to start rejected requests for that ID.

  - Getting a request for a blacklisted ID will only happen due to a race condition across Teams. I.e. TeamB has blacklisted the ID, but TeamC has not and TeamC calls TeamB with the blacklisted ID. This is an edge case. However it is not guaranteed that it will never happen again, it could totally happen that TeamB gets a request with a blacklisted ID after a year - TeamB must reject that ID.
- ID length will be up to 256chars.
- There is no repository to check whether a given ID is blacklisted or not.
- TeamB has around ~200hosts in the fleet.

  - Hosts are deployed to on a daily basis - which causes a restart.

---

Tenets to follow for design:

- TeamB's availability should not be affected.
- API latency should not increase.
- If possible, avoid a adding a new dependency.

Options considered:

- **A**: TeamB adds all blacklisted IDs to a DB (Dynamo) which is then checked during all of its API requests.

  - Con: Adds latency to its API.
  - Con: Adds dependency on Dynamo - which effects its availability.
  - Con: Expensive to check DB just to handle an edge case.
- **B**: TeamB stores all of the IDs in a local CSV file (or some format) which gets updated every 30days via cron job. Which TeamB then downloads locally every 30days as well, and loads into memory at startup.

  - Con: With 5000 IDs per day being added, it might not be scalable in the future (when the file size gets into the GBs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [bloom filter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). A Bloom filter is a space-efficient probabilistic data structure that is used to test whether an element is a member of a set. A bloom filter can have some false positives, but never false negatives, so anything caught by the filter, you'll need to do an actual check against the full list, which likely resides in a centralised/clustered database. A bloom filter is space efficient, so you can distribute the bloom filter to all machines frequently, while keeping the full list on a smaller, more manageable number of hosts.

You can set the false positive rate to an acceptable rate, so that, for example, 99% of requests can be accepted by the bloom filter and won't need to go through the full list.

Answer (score 0):

Simple db source of truth with a basic admin site (ideally managed by team A). Some listener for messages that updates the DB. API checks the DB (or some intermediary service, ideally managed by team A), using a simple in memory cache (with a simple ttl refresh if your hosts aren’t guaranteed to restart in the 30 day window) - or some distributed cache like Redis if team B already uses one or if you want to trade latency for consistency (and when your denylist gets large).